# How to access default page models in template wagtail

Tags: django-models, wagtail

So this awesome Wagtail/Django framework is nice!
I like it allot.

Still getting used to but seems straight forward,
What I do not understand tho is how can I access default page models and render them in the templates?

So Wagtail has this models that you make based on their Page class.

```
class SomeClass(Page):
    """
    Some text
    """
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    body_small = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

All good and well.
Now my page template looks like this

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block base_content %}

    {{ page.intro }}
    {{ page.body_small }}

{% endblock %}
```

Now I want to add the settings model items like Published Date.
Those are default from Wagtail, see:
[image]

What page model do I need to use?

```
{{ page.published_date }} //Does not work
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in the Settings tab are available as `{{ page.go_live_at }}` and `{{ page.expire_at }}`. However, these are only used for scheduled publishing so may not be a particularly relevant thing to output on the page - `{{ page.first_published_at }}` and `{{ page.last_published_at }}` are probably more useful. See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html for more.

Comment: Thank you, ```{{ page.first_published_at }}``` works, but is there some way to convert the output to ```30 May 2018``` instead of the now ```May 30, 2018, 10:11 a.m.```

Comment: nevermind, used jinja templating for formating date like so: ```{{ date.strftime(format) }}```